How can I handle EOF when it can legally occur in other places rather than just after a line-ending?
I'm writing a parser with winnow 0.6.7, to parse a text file that has simple lines like this:
.DIRECTIVE 0 1   // a comment
.MODE 0 "ignore me"

Usually every line ends in \n or \r\n, but in some cases the last line in the file may not have a newline, and thus the line ends with EOF. It could be a valid line with no line-ending, or it could be a blank line (no characters).
I'm having trouble writing a parser for this because eof is not considered a consumable part of the input. This means that it cannot be used in repeat parsers that might match an empty line, because this would cause the parser to match on zero input (since EOF is not consumed) and thus the winnow infinite loop check kicks in and prevents the parser from being run.
For example, this is not valid:
    repeat(0.., (space0, alt((eof, line_ending))))

What's the best practice for handling an EOF that might occur anywhere that any other rule might terminate, especially final blank lines?

You need to (1) consider the newline as a separator, not a terminator, and (2) allow empty statements, for the case where the file does end with a newline.
